# Self referential association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to figure out how to do a self referencing association in Rails. I'm a Rails beginner.

Basically, I have a model `Group`. Each Group can have many sub-groups. I feel like I've tried everything, but I can't get the join to work.

What I have now is

```
# GroupSubGroup Model
class GroupSubGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :sub_group, class_name: 'Group'
end
```

and then my Group Model looks like

```
     has_many :group_sub_groups
     has_many :sub_groups, foreign_key: :sub_group_id, through: :group_sub_groups, class_name: 'GroupSubGroup'
     has_many :groups, through: :sub_groups
     has_many :groups, class_name: 'GroupSubGroup'
```

And my migration looks like

```
    create_table :group_sub_groups do |t|
      t.integer :group_id, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :groups }
      t.references :sub_group, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :groups }

      t.timestamps
    end
```

My main issue is that I can add a new `GroupSubGroup` row into the join table using `parent_group.sub_groups.new`, however when I retrieve the parent group and loop over it's `sub_groups`, none of the instances are of the `Group` class and therefore don't have any of the methods.

For example

```
Group.all.each do |group|
      group.sub_groups.each do |s|
        puts "#{s.name} is a sub group for #{group.name}"
      end
    end
```

Throws an `undefined method 'name'` error.

Comment: Do your SubGroup has `name` as a column? Assuming you are doing migration correctly, the error message you gave only give hint that your SubGroup does not have `name` as a column.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually a lot simpler then this. You don't need a separate model/table for subgroups. Which is the whole of the point of a self referential association.

Lets just start out with the groups table and add our self-refential foreign key:

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.references :parent, index: true, foreign_key: { to_table: :groups }
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then lets create a one-to-many association to the same table:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, 
    class_name: 'Group',
    inverse_of: :sub_groups
  has_many :sub_groups, 
    class_name: 'Group',
    foreign_key: 'parent_id',
    inverse_of: :parent
  scope :top_level, ->{ where(parent_id: nil) } 
end
```

You can then iterate through the top-level groups and their subgroups with:

```
# eager_load prevents an n+1 query
Group.top_level.eager_load(:sub_groups).each do |group|
  group.sub_groups.each do |s|
    puts "#{s.name} is a sub group for #{group.name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be how you set up the associations

```
has_many :group_sub_groups

# The following should suffice for sub groups.  This should return all
# sub_groups that the group has
has_many :sub_groups, through: :group_sub_groups, source: :sub_group

# The following should suffice for groups.  This should return all groups
# where the group is a sub_group of.
has_many :groups, through: :group_sub_groups, source: :group
```

For the following code

```
Group.all.each do |group|
  group.sub_groups.each do |s|
    puts "#{s.name} is a sub group for #{group.name}"
  end
end
```

The error is most probably because of `s.name`.  In your original implementation, `sub_groups` has a class of `class_name: 'GroupSubGroup'` which is not what you want.  Using the associations I mentioned above should fix that error.